# Proper syntax for Laravel Eloquent insert/update

Tags: laravel, eloquent, insert, foreign-keys, relationship

I have seemingly simple problem that I still can't solve after days of browsing around.
Say I have Debitur model.

```
class Debitur extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'debiturs';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'address',
    ];

    public function debiturWife(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\DebiturWife');
    }
}
```

And I have a DebiturWife model.

```
class DebiturWife extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'debitur_wifes';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama', 'address', 'photo',
    ];

    public function debitur(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Debitur');
    }
}
```

I can get Debitur and DebiturWife data in the DebiturController like this:

```
return Debitur::with('debiturWife')->find($debitur_id);
```

Now I want to create a new Debitur and DebiturWife, how do I do that?
Something like

```
$debitur = new Debitur;
$debitur->name = $request->name;
$debitur_wife = new Debitur.DebiturWife; //obviously doesn't work
```

Comment: What are the schemas for Debitur and DebiturWife database tables?

Comment: Debitur ( id | name | address ). DebiturWife (id | debitur_id | name | address | photo ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$debitur = new Debitur;
$debitur->name = $request->name;
$debitur->save();

$debitur_wife = new DebiturWife([
    'name' => 'Foo'
]);

$debitur->debiturWife()->save($debitur_wife);
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

*What if later I want to update DebiturWife based on Debitur's id?*

```
$debitur = Debitur::with('debiturWife')->find($id);
$debitur->debiturWife->name = 'new name';
$debitur->debiturWife->address = 'new address';
$debitur->save();
```

Comment: What if later I want to update DebiturWife based on Debitur's id? 
I tried this but doesn't work 
$debitur = Debitur::with('debiturWife')->find($id);
        $debiturWife = debiturWife::where('debitur_id',$id)->update($request->all());
        $debitur->debiturWife()->save($debiturWife);

Comment: The documentation is confusing, I have read it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way:

```
$debitur = new Debitur;
$debitur->name = $request->name;
$debitur->save();

$debitur->debiturWife()->create([
   'name' => $request->name,
   'address' => $request->address,
   'photo' => $request->photo
]);
```

Another way of doing this would be —

```
$debiturWife = new DebiturWife();
$debiturWife->name = $request->name;
$debiturWife->address = $request->address;
$debiturWife->photo = $request->photo;

$debitur->debiturWife()->save($debiturWife);
```

The `debitur_id` will be automatically set. The only difference between the `create` & `save` method is that the `create` method accepts a plain PHP array whereas the `save` method accepts an instance of `DebitureWife`

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) for better understanding.